# Wrong favicon showing up in HNQ list

Tags: bug, design

Travel questions in the Hot Network Questions list are showing up with the beta site icon, e.g.:
[image: Screenshot]

The middle entry links [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/106198/london-on-christmas-day).

Comment: [Also reported on meta.SE.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303883/icons-for-hot-questions-are-wrong) This is a known content synchronization bug that keeps reappearing whenever new SE sites are added.